# .click() not working on firefox in first time angular

Tags: javascript, angular, events, click

I'm facing problem with Firefox. 
I have angular component with viewChild like this :

```
@ViewChild('fileInput', { static: true}) fileInput: ElementRef;
open() {
   this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
}
```

and from parent component I'm runing the open method :

```
@ViewChild('uploadBtn', { static: true }) uploadBtn: FileUploaderComponent;
someMethod() {
   if (someCondition) {
       this.openConfirmation();
   else {
       this.uploadBtn.open();
  }
}
```

in the confirmation I just open confirmation dialog with yes or no. to confirm upload and replace current and change the condition is yes selected.

and run someMethod() again with changed condition to run else ( open() ).
it's working fine on chrome. 
but on firefox it's not working on first click . I have to click twice .
anyone know why this happened ?

Comment: Can you also share how your component html looks like? It might be also an issue with rendering of the templates as each browser have different engines.